# ordena lista c lambda

Tags: classificação

```
alfabeto = {'t':0, 's':1, 'h':2, 'j':3, 'm':4, 'p':5, 'n':6, 'z':7, 'w':8, 'l':9, 'r':10, '    c':11, 'b':12, 'x':13, 'k':14, 'q':15, 'v':16, 'd':17, 'g':18, 'f':19}
d = open('txtA.txt', 'r')
ordenar = []
for line in d:
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in ordenar:
            ordenar.append(word)
        for c in ordenar:
            for i in c:
                ordenado = sorted(line.split(), key=(alfabeto.get(i, ord(i))))
print(ordenado)
```

Esse é um código pra ordenar um texto de forma personalizada, só que ele não está rodando.

Aparece o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

E não estou entendendo o porquê.

Comment: Em qual linha exatamente?

Comment: ordenado = sorted(line.split(), key=(alfabeto.get(i, ord(i))))
nessa

Comment: Em algum lugar vc redefiniu uma das funções da linha?

Comment: como assim? ;-;
As funções utilizadas nessa linha, são do python mesmo.. ;-;

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que `alfabeto.get(i, ord(i))` irá retornar um valor inteiro, seja o valor que está em `alfabeto` ou o respectivo `ord`. Como você passa esse resultado para `key`, ele espera um objeto chamável; como inteiro não é chamável, dá o erro.

Neste caso, você teria que criar uma função que retorna a lista de valores de cada palavra conforme o alfabeto, assim como sugeri nas outras perguntas:

```
def lista_valores(palavra):
    return [alfabeto.get(i, ord(i)) for i in palavra]
```

E utilizar tal função como `key`:

```
for line in d:
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in ordenar:
            ordenar.append(word)
        for c in ordenar:
            for i in c:
                ordenado = sorted(line.split(), key=lista_valores)
print(ordenado)
```

Mas, assim, a função utiliza o objeto `alfabeto` como global, o que nem sempre é uma boa ideia e, neste ponto, a solução poderia ser melhorada. Aliás, tem muito laço de repetição que não fez sentido aí, pois o código abaixo geraria o mesmo resultado:

```
for line in d:
    ordenado = sorted(line.split(), key=lista_valores)
    print(ordenado)
```

Comment: ahhh desculpa. é que esse não é o codigo inteiro. os outros dois for's são pra outra parte do codigo.
Aquele if, é porque o texto tem algumas palavras repetidas, e eu quero eu elas apareçam apenas uma vez na lista ordenada. mas muito obrigada. eu não tinha entendido direito

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta na `key=`, você esta passando um numero quando o esperado deveria ser uma "função" ou um `lambda` (conforme documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Ou seja `sorted` tenta executar o valor retornado de `alfabeto.get(i, ord(i))` como uma função, mas como `alfabeto.get` retorna um dos valores em:

```
{'t':0, 's':1, 'h':2, 'j':3, 'm':4, 'p':5, 'n':6, 'z':7, 'w':8, 'l':9, 'r':10, '    c':11, 'b':12, 'x':13, 'k':14, 'q':15, 'v':16, 'd':17, 'g':18, 'f':19}
```

Ou pega o valor `ord(i)` que é o alternativo dentro do `.get` (veja documentação: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesmapping.html) (não tenho certeza, mas esta função creio que seja usada apenas em Python 2)

Tem que ter certeza do que você quer exatamente usar para ordenar, um exemplo de uso do `key=`, supondo que queira comparar o `alfabeto.get` atual com o item atual gerado pelo `line.split`:

```
sorted(line.split(), key=lambda lineitem: lineitem == alfabeto.get(i, ord(i)))
```

Seria **semelhante** a fazer isto:

```
def comparacao(lineitem):
     return lineitem == outrovaloracomparar
```

Então após o `:` no `lambda` seria o mesmo que o `return`

Note que os códigos acima são somente exemplos, eu realmente não entendi qual tipo de condição você deseja passar para a ordenação, os exemplos são apenas para entender como deve-se usar `lambda` ou `def` com `key=`, então basta adaptar a sua necessidade.